# Pass a dataframe in an API call with FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a file called `main.py` as follows:

```
from typing import List, Dict
from fastapi import Body, FastAPI
import pandas as pd

@app.post("/")
async def read_df(data: List[Dict], id_process: int = Body(...)):
    return {"id_process": id_process, "data": data}
```

Now, if I run the code for the test, saved in the file `test_main.py`, that is:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from main import app
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame([[0.2, 0.8], [0.9, 0.1]], columns=["c1", "c2"])

json_df = json.loads(df.to_json(orient="records"))

client = TestClient(app)

def test_read_df():
    response = client.post(
        "/",
        json={
            "id_process": 1,
            "data": json_df # (1)
        }
    )
    return response.json()

print(test_read_df())
```

I get, as excepted:

```
{'id_process': 1, 'data': [{'c1': 0.2, 'c2': 0.8}, {'c1': 0.9, 'c2': 0.1}]}
```

Is this the standard way to pass a dataframe in an API call? Or is there a way to directly pass the dataframe `df` in # (1)? My goal is always to return the dictionary above.

Answer (score 0):

The Process seems to be better, There are some modules like "beneath". Yet this method has the less execution time.

I suggest to continue with this.